# Searching Vector of Structs for String C++

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I am attempting to compare a string against a struct element in a vector of structs. I have created the vector correctly, but cannot seem to get the if statement to work. It always returns true. What is the proper way to do this?

Struct:

```cpp
struct customer{
    string name;
    string phoneNumber;
    string addressLine1;
    string addressLine2;
};
```

Loop to iterate over vector containing if statement:

```cpp
cout<<"Input customer's phone number: ", cin>>phoneNumber, cout<<endl;
int foundIndex = 0;
bool found = false;
for(int it = 1; it < customers.size(); it++){
    if(phoneNumber.compare(customers[it].phoneNumber)){
        cout<<"Found at "<<foundIndex<<endl;
        cout<<"Name: "<<customers[foundIndex].name<<endl;
        cout<<"Phone Number: "<<customers[foundIndex].phoneNumber<<endl;
        cout<<"Address: "<<customers[foundIndex].addressLine1<<endl<<"                 "<<customers[foundIndex].addressLine2<<endl;
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Function to populate Vector from CSV:

```cpp
vector<customer> readFile(void){
    string name;
    string phoneNumber;
    string addressLine1;
    string addressLine2;
    vector<customer> customers;
    vector<string> temper;
    customer temp;
    fstream ioFile;
    ioFile.open("customers.csv", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
    while (!ioFile.eof()){
        getline(ioFile, name);
        temper = split(name);
        temp.name = temper[0];
        temp.phoneNumber = temper[1];
        temp.addressLine1 = temper[2];
        temp.addressLine2 = temper[3];
        customers.push_back(temp);
    }

    ioFile.close();
    return customers;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `std::string::compare`? Why not `==`, `!=`?

Comment: Missing closing `)` in `if(phoneNumber.compare(customers[it].phoneNumber)` ?

Comment: @erip As far as I was taught, you cannot compare strings with `==`.

Comment: @hansmaad Copy and paste typo. It is does correctly in the actual code.

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos Sure you can. Not in Java, but this is C++.

Comment: `compare` returns 0 if strings are equal.

Comment: @erip Changed to `==` and it still returns the first entry.

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: you dont actually set `foundIndex` to anything when you find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the code you wrote should work, but There are some Issues you have overseen

1. A Vector starts at index 0. so you should start at index 0 with iterating
2. You are initialising foundIndex=0 but foundIndex never changes (and for this 
   code snippet it is not necessary.
   I have modified your code . It should work now

   ```
   cout<<"Input customer's phone number: ", cin>>phoneNumber, cout<<endl;
   bool found = false;
   for(int it = 0; it < customers.size(); it++){
           if(phoneNumber.compare(customers[it].phoneNumber){
               cout<<"Found at "<<it<<endl;
               cout<<"Name: "<<customers[it].name<<endl;
               cout<<"Phone Number: "<<customers[it].phoneNumber<<endl;
               cout<<"Address: "<<customers[it].addressLine1<<endl<<"                 "<<customers[it].addressLine2<<endl;
               found = true;
               break;
           }
   }
   ```

Do you recognize that I use "it"?
If you need foundIndex
add

```
foundIndex=it;
```

before

```
    break;
```

Without changing FoundIndex you always will get the first entry.

Comment: this could not possible compile. also, isn't the condition reversed?

Answer (score 3):

The standard library provides [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) function to search a container using a custom predicate.

```
std::vector<customer> customers;

auto result = std::find_if(
    customers.begin(),
    customers.end(),
    [&phoneNumber](customer const& c) {
        return c.phoneNumber == phoneNumber;
    }
);

if (result != customers.end()) {
    std::cout << *result << '\n';
}
```

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos if you actually clicked the link behind it, you'd see that it's a part of the `<algorithm>` header you need to include.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

phoneNumber.compare(customers[it].phoneNumber)

by

phoneNumber.compare(customers[it].phoneNumber) == 0

Explanation: compare is a metric and returns zero if no difference exists.
So, for example, "Foo".compare("Bar") > 0, and therefore evaluates as true, while "Foo".compare("Foo") = 0 which would evaluate as false if used as boolean value.

See examples in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Answer (score 1):

[`std::string::compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) returns `0` if the strings are equal. `phoneNumber.compare(customers[it].phoneNumber)` will be false for matching number and true for wrong number. Just use the `==` operator:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < customers.size(); ++i) 
{
    if (customers[i].phoneNumber == phoneNumber) 
    {
        std::cout << "Found: " << customers[i].name;
        break;
    }
}
```

To improve the code, you could use the [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) template from standard lib:

```
auto it = std::find_if(begin(customers), end(customers),
                      [&phoneNumber](const customer& c) { 
                          return c.phoneNumber == phoneNumber; 
                      });

if (it != end(customers))
    std::cout << it->name;
```